# Access IP Camera using imutils VideoStream

Tags: python-3.x, video-streaming, imutils

I'm using the line below to fetch video stream from my laptop camera and it works great.

```
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
```

But now, I want the source to be an IP Camera and not my laptop camera. Is there a way like just changing the src to the IP of the camera? I've searched all over and what I mostly saw was using the cv2 VideoCapture method. I'm wondering if that solution will also work with VideoStream function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First make a variable, setting login credentials of IP camera.
Example

```
rtsp_url = "rtsp://name:password/video"
vs = VideoStream(rtsp_url).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made it work.

For future references, yes. The method used by cv2 VideoCapture function also works on imutils' VideoStream function.

Comment: I've tried passing in the ip address of the camera like this:. `VideoStream(src='rtsp://abc.de.fg.h').start()` but it still doesn't work. It just defaults to my webcam. Please what exactly did you do?

Comment: I've solved my issue. I rewrote everything using cv2.